# How to run QTcpServer in separate thread from GUI in PySide6?

Tags: qt, pyside, qthread, qtcpserver

I'm making a PySide6 program with a GUI, backend, and a QTcpServer (which only handles a single connection), and I want all three in separate threads as to never freeze up the GUI.

I read about implementing the run() function in QThread, but the backend and the server are entirely event-driven, so this seems like a bad solution. Is there a way to just place the whole QTcpServer and backend instances in separate threads?

Comment: QTcpServer can already work asynchronously, being it a QObject. It's also not clear what you mean by "backend" and what type of events you're talking about. In any case, the most important thing is that the UI *must* be the main thread (UI elements can only be created there). If your backend is not based on Qt events and has its own event loop, then run it in a separate thread.

Comment: Oh I see. I made a QRunner implementation which just instantiates my QTcpServer and start it with a QThreadPool, and self.thread() shows the server and GUI are in separate threads. Thank you! I'm getting some threading errors like "QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread." but I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

> Note: My TCP_Server is a singleton, not sure if you would need a reference to it otherwise, so it doesn't go out of scope.

```
class ServerThread(QRunnable):
    @Slot()
    def run(self):
        TCP_Server()


threadpool = QThreadPool()
server = ServerThread()
threadpool.start(server)
```